# Run function on JFrame close

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

```
void terminate() {}
protected JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

How can I get `frame` to run the terminate function when I press the close button?

Edit: I tried to run this, but for some reason it doesn't print test (however, the program closes). Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("test");
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [addWindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener%28java.awt.event.WindowListener%29):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // call terminate
    }
});
```

See [void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) and [Class WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) too.

Comment: Will I have to create a new class that extends JFrame and implements WindowAdapter? (or is it ok to keep frame as a JFrame?)

It doesn't really work yet, and I get the warning "The method WindowClosed(WindowEvent) from the type new WindowAdapter(){} is never used locally" on the WindowClosing function

Comment: `windowClosing` and not `WindowClosing` with uppercase `W`.

Answer (score 20):

Not only do you have to add the window listener, you have to set the default close operation to do nothing on close.  This allows your code to execute.

```java
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        exitProcedure();
    }
});
```

Finally, you have to call System exit to actually stop your program from running.

```
public void exitProcedure() {
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but especially `@Override`.  Very good advice.  No (reconsiders) ***excellent advice***.  :)

Comment: Remove the frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 2):

`Frame.dispose()` method does not terminate the program. To terminate the program you need to call `System.exit(0)` method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to terminate your program after the JFrame is closed, you have to set the default close operation on your JFrame.

In your constructor of your JFrame write:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

If you just want to call a method when the window is closed and not terminate the whole program, than go with the answer of Maroun.

Comment: I would like to do both (run a function, then terminate). Here's my current code:

  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("test");
    frame.dispose();
   }
  });

The problem is that it doesn't print "test". Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: The method is "windowClosing" not "WindowClosing". You need to override it, so it has to be the exact name.