# Windowclosing event of Java jframe api

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I make the Java Socket Chatting program. but I have a question about WindowAdapter.

Belows are my main codes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clientgui clientgui = new Clientgui();
        clientgui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                String str = "end"+" : "+clientgui.getIdname();
                clientgui.getPw().println(str);
                clientgui.getPw().flush();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I used Frame, windowClosing was working. but When I used JFrame, windowClosing wasn’t working.
I want to know the best API about Jframe.
Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

**== UPDATE ==**

My point is that, when I close the clientgui Jframe window, there is no closing event from Windowsadapter class. so I want to know window Jframe closing API to catch the Jframe Windowclosing event.
I hope these help you understand my situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "wasn't working"? Can you explain what's wrong, what you expected and what actually happens? Also, showing `Clientgui` is also helpful to show, if you want an answer.

Comment: See this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372241/run-function-on-jframe-close/16372860#16372860) for a working example of a JFrame window closing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Kindly check my update.

Comment: What's the setDefaultCloseOperation on your JFrame?

Comment: A WindowListener works on both Frame and JFrame. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem. So create a JFrame and add the WindowListener to the frame. Then entire class will be about 10 lines of code. Once you prove it works you then debug your application to see what you are doing differently. The code you posted here does not help solve the problem.